# Laravel 5.4 eloquent one to many relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm refreshing my knowledge about Laravel eloquent relationships. Unfortunately, i'm unable to solve/find a problem with a one to many relationship. Someone any idea/suggestion what is wrong with my code?

**What is happening**

Eloquent does not find any related data from the mobiles table. [Current result (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/7mcN5T9E)

**What should happen**

Getting all related data from the mobile table.

### Involved  code

I'm working on a clean Laravel 5.4 installation. This is the only code i created/added.

**User model**

```
public function phone(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Mobile', 'user_id', 'id');

}
```

> With this function eloquent will get all records from the mobile table where column user_id == id  right?

**User table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Mobile table**

```
 Schema::create('mobiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('user_id');

        $table->string('phoneNumber');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: And in your `Mobil` model use `public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}` and add `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` in the `mobiles` migration

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doenst work. I will start learning  eloquent relationships again.

Comment: How are you fetching the results? What's the query?

Comment: I select a user using User::find(); i call ->phone(); on the result of find.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your codes, I think the problem lies in your model. It should be like as follows:

**User table**

```
protected $fillable=['name', 'email' , 'password'];

public function Mobile(){

    return $this->hasMany(Mobile::class);

}
```

**Mobile table**

```
protected $fillable=['user_id', 'phonenumber'];

public function User(){

    return $this->hasMany(User::class);

}
```

You need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Given that you are calling correctly from database, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Maraboc in the comments section, create a `user` function with the content

```
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This solved my problem